# Send outlook instance over network

Tags: c#, networking, outlook

I've got an Outlook tool that works on the client(PC-A) and this tool set some folder permission. Now I want to set the settings remotely over my computer (PC-B) so I dont have to go to all employers.

I've searched in google but there aren't any useful information for me and beside this I don't know how to code this. A friend told me that I can use a service for this or code a server/client that listen to PC-A.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: So you are saying you want to get "some folder" settings present on PC-A(Client) and set the "some folder" settings on PC-B(Your Machine). Am I reading this right ?

Comment: No. My outlook tool set the settings on the client. I don't want to walk to all the employers to use my tool. I want something like a "server". This "server" is on my computer PC-B and I can just grab the outlook instance from PC-A and display it in my "server-tool". Hope this description is a bit more useful.

Comment: You mean you want to look at all the Clients settings from your server and not go to individual machine ?

Comment: Yeah thats what i want :D

Comment: I just need a decision. Using Services or code a server my self. I'm very unexpirenced in Server/Client or Services and I don't know where to start

Comment: I just posted my answer. I am not big fan of services so my view might be biased. End of the day choose the approach which is more stable than fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more than one way to do it. I am sorry I don't have specific code examples but simple steps on how to. Maybe you can expand on that.

***Assumption : Clients and your server are in a LAN and in the same domain.***

**Solution1:** You can have a daily or scheduled job collating the settings you need and pushing it to a centralized DB. The server (your machine) can then poll the centralized DB for the settings. Depending on how you design the table design you can have the client module change the settings based on the settings you make on the server. Since everything is on the centralized DB, client and the server hit the DB to get the information. A little complex but not much simpler to understand.

**Solution2:** Using the System.Net.Sockets to create a custom server and client listening on specific ports. [Tech.pro](http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server) has a good [article](http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server) on it.

***Assumption : Your clients are on Internet and you are also on the world wide web and not in the same domain.***

**Solution1:** The DB approach seems quite solid and it gives you the ability to maintain different settings for different users and have more customized approach. You can push and pull the data as Json so that the network bandwidth is not heavily utilized.

**Solution:** TCP approach should work good assuming you are connected directly to the internet and not through proxy. I am not sure about hits approach but it is one way.

Alternatively you can implement Solution 1 or 2 using a service, but personally I would prefer a process running on my machine only when it needs to.

Feel free to correct me.

Comment: We just misunderstand each other XD

I got my tool (local on the client of the employer), that pulls the current mailbox of the logged in employer in Windows. This tool grab the current outlook session and set the folder permission recursivly.

I want to create a new Tool(Tool-A), that grab the outlook session from the employer to my computer (Tool-B). Now I can just edit the folder permissions and send it back to Tool-A. Damn it's so hard to explain in english

Comment: I think I understand wat you are saying, you want to edit certain permissions using "employers" outlook session object on your machine and then push the session object to employer so that the change can be done. Right ? 1st off I don't think its possible to send an Outlook session over the network. The session is local to that machine and bringing it over the network,even if it was possible, will not work. And it should not work becoz when you use the session you effectively impersonate the user using the session. That would be a security problem. Feel free to correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: You're right. Well thats really difficult. Are there any chances to get the Credentials from the other user over network? If yes, then i can just use those credentials to create a new session on my machine with this credentials.

Comment: Being the domain administrator can/might give you the access to the user's mailbox but I doubt you can pass it over the network. Why do you need the specific session to change the permission ? Maybe you can satisfy the requirement by changing the design of the implementation

Comment: The reason why I want to do it like this is: I dont have access to the Exchange server. If you want to give sb permission to your folder in outlook, you have to click every single subfolder in outlook and set the permission for this folder manuelly. My tool set the permission recursivly to all subfolders. If I can get the credentials, then I can create a new session with those credentials.

Comment: Getting the credentials is definitely not going to be possible especially if you don't have access to Exchange server. And I don't think its a wise to impersonate a user on a different machine than the one the user is using. It creates a lot security loop holes. Maybe you can write a small application or outlook-addin that can do this but "triggered" by the user in his/her own machine.

Comment: hmm ok it seems that it dont work like this. Thanks a lot for your time. Some points for you as a reward ^^

Comment: Thank You @TuVi. Maybe if you change the design of the implementation so that all is happening on the local machine.